# Promise.all().then() gets executed before the promise.all() complete

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to wrap my head around `Promises`, but my code doesn't work the way it should. My goal is to show that the table has loaded after all the promises are complete, but instead the code in `then` (`"table loaded"` and `[undefined, undefined] 'res'`) get executed before. What is the way to make it work, waiting untill the table was filled?

My code

```js
async function updateTable(accno, entity, start = null, funds) {
  $table.bootstrapTable('removeAll')
  prms = []

  return Promise.all(
    accno.map(
      acc => {
        let conf = {
          method: 'get',
          url: 'url',
          params: {
            account_number: acc,
            start: start,
            entity: entity,
          }
        }

        axios(conf).then(function(response) {
          let data = response.data

          data_combined = []

          for (let j = 0; j < data.return.length; j++) {
            let row = data.return[j]
            let temp = {
              id: data.id,
              // assigining more data here
            }

            data_combined.push(temp)
          }

          //another request deleted to simplify

          fund_array = []

          tableLoadAnimation('id-table-load', 'remove-all')
          superset = [...superset, ...data_combined, ...fund_array]
          $table.bootstrapTable('load', superset)
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
      })
  ).then((a) => {
    console.log('table loaded');
    return a
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res, "res") // returns [undefined, undefined] 'res'
    return res

  })
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything in your `.map()` calback, therefore `Promise.all()` doesn't wait for any promises to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Since `axios` returns promise, I had to return `axios` in `map`

```
async function updateTable(accno, entity, start = null, funds) {
  $table.bootstrapTable('removeAll')
  prms = []

  prms =  Promise.all(
    accno.map(
      acc => {
        let conf = {
          method: 'get',
          url: 'url',
          params: {
            account_number: acc,
            start: start,
            entity: entity,
          }
        }

        return axios(conf).then(function(response) {
          let data = response.data

          data_combined = []

          for (let j = 0; j < data.return.length; j++) {
            let row = data.return[j]
            let temp = {
              id: data.id,
              // assigining more data here
            }

            data_combined.push(temp)
          }

          //another request deleted to simplify

          fund_array = []

          tableLoadAnimation('id-table-load', 'remove-all')
          superset = [...superset, ...data_combined, ...fund_array]
          $table.bootstrapTable('load', superset)
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
      })
  ).then((a) => {
    console.log('table loaded');
    return a
  })
}
```